# How to create border EditField in Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How to create EditField within Blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such direct API. You need to override the EditField class and implement the subLayout and paint method. Here is the code sample.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {         
        int oldColor = Color.BLACK;
        g.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRoundRect(padding.getLeft(), padding.getTop(), managerWidth,getPreferredHeight(), 10, 10);
        g.setColor(oldColor);    
        super.paint(g);
    }

    public void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        super.sublayout(managerWidth + padding.getLeft(), getPreferredHeight());
        super.setExtent(managerWidth + padding.getLeft(), getPreferredHeight());
}
```